# When i put input in arabic language store in database like ''??? ?? ? ????" how can i fix it with sqlserver

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

when i put input text in Arabic language it store in table unknown text in my database in sqlsrv

ex: "اهلا بك"
it will store in my table -> "?? ????"

It is my Controller

```
$yourDay = new YouDay();
$yourDay->Feeling = $request->feeling   ;
$yourDay->Reason = $request->reason ;
```

Comment: Either your parameter or your column is not using NVARCHAR type. Use Unicode compatible data storage from start to finish

Comment: What encoding is your PHP, db connector, and DB using?

Comment: No my column Data type is nvarchar(MAX) but it still give me this error

Comment: it is in database.php 
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',

Comment: Something somewhere between your app and the dB is not using Unicode, for example this will insert garbage `insert into table(col) values 'اهلا بك'`) because it’s missing the N before the Arabic string. Examine how you do your queries; they should be using Unicode parameters not ascii string concatenation etc

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the values like this:

```
declare @t table (name nvarchar(50))

insert into @t values (N'اهلا بك')

select * from @t
```